# Complex const declarations in C++

Tags: c++, constants, re2

I'm taking my first foray into C++, specifically the Google RE2 library, and I am stuck on some of the syntax. I am trying to invoke a function with the signature:

```
static bool FindAndConsumeN(StringPiece* input, const RE2& pattern,
                         const Arg* const args[], int argc);
```

With the code:

```
const re2::RE2::Arg match;
bool isMatched = RE2::FindAndConsumeN(&inputPiece, *expression,new const re2::RE2::Arg[] { &match },0)
```

However I am getting the compiler error:

```
Error   3   error C2664: 're2::RE2::FindAndConsumeN' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const re2::RE2::Arg (*)[]' to 'const re2::RE2::Arg *const []'
```

I've clearly got the datatype of the third argument wrong, but does anyone know what the correct data type is?

I am compiling the code with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: It's not *exception*, it's compiler error. Press F1 key when you see it.

Comment: also please learn the language first. `NULL` is not `0`.

Comment: @Abyx: also, please read the standard first, `NULL` is "an integral constant expression with the value 0".

Comment: Abyx comment is ridiculous, the 0 matches the int argc parameter.

Comment: Sorry chaps, I've corrected that usage of NULL, however it has not affected the compiler output.

Comment: Using `NULL` in place of an `int` will cause the compiler to issue a warning, at least with some compilers.

Comment: @Matteo Italia, you forgot about semantics.

Comment: don't use `new` statement, it will leak memory here.

Comment: @Abyx: You have a point, but I got confused because there have been several edits. When I first wrote the comment I didn't notice where `NULL` was used, then I saw it and I wrote that you were right about the semantics, but when I edited the comment the code was already fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use code like this:

```
re2::RE2::Arg match;
re2::RE2::Arg* args[] = { &match };
re2::RE2::FindAndConsumeN(NULL, pattern, args, 1);
```

`args` will be converted to `const Arg* args[]`.

The inner `const` has no deal with calling code, it works only within `FindAndConsumeN`.

Don't use `new` because you can't `delete` array later.
(with `new` it would be `new const re2::RE2::Arg*[]`)

Comment: To add to that, the `consts` in an argument list are just a guarantee that the function will not modify what you pass in. You can always provide a non-`const` where an argument is declared `const`. You just have to provide it the correct base type.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that you need a pointer to constant data, not a constant pointer to data. Use an intermediate variable to store the value of the offending argument, and I think you'll be able to sort the problem.

Comment: Could you expand on that, or point me in the direction of some resources that can explain more fully?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that parameter declarations have slightly different meanings
when they appear as function parameters.  In this case, the actual type
of the third parameter is: `Arg const* const*`.  I don't think you can
use a `new expression` here (and if you could, who'd delete it); the new
expression required would be something like `new (Arg const* const 
[n])`; which allocates an array of `n` uninitialized const pointers.
What you need is something more along the lines of:

```
std::vector<Arg const*> args;
//  Fill out args with the desired data...
... , &args[0], ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The function signature is:

```
static bool FindAndConsumeN(StringPiece* input, const RE2& pattern,
                            const Arg* const args[], int argc);
```

The 3rd argument is  const Arg* const args[], this means:
constant array of const pointers to type Arg.

i.e. the array is constant and each entry is also const.

Comment: Thanks mark, but I was more wondering how I could construct an object of that type to pass in.